# Como pasar el valor de una variable a otra declarara antes

Tags: php, php5

Tengo este código en el cual me resuelve una operación la cual necesita el valor W para poder ser calcula, con base en ese resultado hacer el IF y volver hacer la operación, pero con la nueva W calculada, mi duda es como puedo asignar la W para que vuelva a efectuar la operación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Deberías inicializarla antes del `for` y ya después irá cambiando de valor en cada iteración del bucle

Comment: Entiendo que te refieres a una recursión, es decir, si $w cambia de valor entonces volver a ejecutar todo el código desde el principio. Si es eso simplemente pon todo ese código en una función y haz que la llame cuando haya una nueva W. Con los datos que nos has proporcionado poco más te puedo decir ni ayudar, pues todo eso me lo estoy suponiendo y voy a ciegas sin ver un [example] con datos de inicio de todas las variables y el resultado esperado. Léete [ask] para aprender a formular mejores preguntas, y no peges imágenes con código pues no ayudan a ayudarte.